# package silence "\sl@warningCount ..."

Tags: silence

The following warning message appears when I using "silence".

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{"packageName"}{"message"}
\documentclass[...]{}
```

then, the error message pops up like,

## "\sl@WarningCount=\count83 ........."

How do I turn off this message

Comment: What happens if you put the document class first? What compiler are you using? You need to provide a complete example, or we cannot duplicate your problem.

Comment: Are you using TeXMaker?

Comment: yes I use TexMaker, and I use silence package as written in the manual

Answer (score 1):

You could suppress these low-level *information* messages by altering the allocation routine macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\e@alloc}{\wlog}{\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newcount\mycount
\end{document}
```

Comment: hmm,. in my case, that is not working..
Anyway, thank you for your comment :)

Comment: @S.Whang If you have an older kernel, you'll want to patch `\alloc@` not `\e@alloc`.